# Eigenvalues of $A+A^{T}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, transpose

Knowing the eigenvalues of $A$, what we can say about the eigenvalues of $A+A^{T}$?

I know that $A$ and $A^T$ have the same spectrum, but also I think that it is not true that $\lambda_{i,(A+A^T)} = 2\lambda_{i,A}$ where $\lambda_{i,A}$ is the $i$-th eigenvalue of $A$. 
For example if $A$ is a orthogonal matrix we have: $A+A^T=A+A^{-1}$ and thus $\lambda_{i,(A+A^T)} = \lambda_{i,A} + \frac{1}{\lambda_{i,A}}$.

Comment: How can you write $\lambda_{i,(A+A^T)} = \lambda_{i,A} + \frac{1}{\lambda_{i,A}}$? Other than the fact that it's not true that an eigenvalue of the sum of two matrices is the sum of two eigenvalues respectively, this expression still doesn't make any sense if I start relabeling eigenvalues of one of the matrices.

Comment: It is not true? The $i$-th engevalue of $A^{-1}$ is equal to the inverse of the  $i$-th engevalue of $A$

Comment: Considering that the eigenvalues are evaluated by a determinant it's not always true that $$\det(A+B)=\det(A)+\det(B)$$ so you cannot say that

Comment: Ok, I understand that, thanks. So we cannot say anything.

Comment: I am a bit confused now, for it seems to me that what Alex said in his/her post was correct. If $A$ is orthogonal, then it is diagonalizable (over $\Bbb C$) and hence $A$ and $A^{-1}$ are simultaneously diagonalizable. But then the eigenvalues of $A+A^{-1}$ are really of the form described above…

Comment: But sorry for istance for the matrix [[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[1,0,0]] it is true that $\lambda_{i,(A+A^T)}=\lambda_{i,A}+\frac{1}{\lambda_{i,A}}$ Why? Is it only a coincidence?

Comment: @Claudius Can you explain why? I mean it is clear know that we cannot say anything about the eigenvalues of $A+A^{T}$ but what we can say about $A+A^{-1}$?

Comment: What do you mean with "explain why"? Didn't I explain what I claimed?

Comment: @Mathematician42 The ordering is given by a choice of eigenbasis. Or, can you tell me why my reasoning is wrong?

Comment: Sorry, brainfarts on my complaints on the ordering :D Still, I don't believe the statement. On the other hand, real eigenvalues of orthogonal matrices are $1$ or $-1$, a counterexample will be a bit more involved.

Comment: @Mathematician42 but sorry $\lambda_{1} = i$ should correspond to $\mu_{2}=\frac{1}{\lambda_{1}}=-i$ and not to $\mu_{1}$ and so the things works

Comment: @Mathematician42 If you still don't believe the statement for the eigenvalues of $A+A^{-1}$ then could you tell me, which part of my explanation is erroneous? (Also, I believe now that the statement for the eigenvalues of $A+A^{-1}$ holds for arbitrary matrices -- since both matrices can be simultaneously put in upper triangular form (over $\Bbb C$).)

Answer (score 2):

On [this forum post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52578/eigenvalues-of-sum-of-a-non-symmetric-matrix-and-its-transpose-aat) on MathOverflow the user Denis Serre gave some interesting insights. Probably is the most you can say about your problem

Answer (score 2):

$A^{T}$ can be equal to $-A$ so there is hardly anything you can say about eigen values of $A+A^{T}$.