# Eigenvalues of $A +A^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse

Knowing the eigenvalues of $A$, what we can say about the eigenvalues of $A+A^{-1}$?

Is it true that $\lambda_{i,(A+A^{-1})} = \lambda_{i,A} + \frac{1}{\lambda_{i,A}}$, where $\lambda_{i,A}$ is the $i$-th eigenvalue of $A$?

I ask this question after asking [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2867843/eigenvalues-of-aat?noredirect=1#comment5918154_2867843), due to the different opinion in the conversation in the comment.

Comment: Consider $A$ already in Jordan normal form. Without loss, consider it is reduced to one block. What can be said about $A+A^{-1}$ in this situation? (Please always show the own work!)

Comment: Yes sorry, i just asked this question due to the comments in the conversation in a my previous question!

Comment: The other question was involving the transpose, there is no connection. In this case, please work out some simple examples, show at least why do you expect the claim to be true or false (mathematically). For instance for a diagonal matrix, then for a $2\times 2$ matrix of the shape $$A  = \begin{bmatrix}a&1\\0&a\end{bmatrix}\ .$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a [Schur decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition) of $A$: $A = UTU^{*}$, where $T$ is upper triangular with eigenvalues $\lambda_j(A)$ on the diagonal and $U$ is unitary matrix. Clear that $A^{-1} = U T^{-1} U^{*}$, where $T^{-1}$ is again an upper triangular matrix with eigenvalues $1/\lambda_j(A)$ of $A^{-1}$ on the diagonal. Then $A + A^{-1} = U (T + T^{-1}) U^{*}$ which implies that eigenvalues of $A + A^{-1}$ are exactly $\lambda_j(A) + 1/\lambda_j(A)$

Comment: Why do you not allow Alex to make his own effort to elucidate the structure? The question comes with no context. No effort / example is shown in the OP. It is maybe not a good idea to give a full answer. By the way, the OP does not say anything about the field of definition of the matrix $A$. (Why it should be defined over a field of characteristic zero includded in $\Bbb C$?)